# Why chain of commands that runs fine on local doesn't run on SSH?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, grep, tail

There's something funny with tail -f and grep -o combination when running over ssh.

So on local server, if you do

```
tail -f /path/myfile.log |grep -o keyword
```

It grep just fine. But if you run it on remote server....

```
ssh user@server 'tail -f /path/myfile.log |grep -o keyword'
```

doesn't work. Nothing comes back as if it was redirected to /dev/null!

But if you remove -f from tail or -o from grep, work just fine... weird :-/

Of course I could create a script on the remote server and just run the script! But that's not quite suitable for my situation.

Comment: Different flavors of linux? different options set in system config files?  there could be many reasons....

Comment: How about privileges to execute in remote server?.

Comment: Here is a post that should be helpful.

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21920/ssh-output-isnt-line-buffered

Answer (score 2):

Apparantly SSH doesn't do line buffering without a terminal.

ssh -t ensures that pseudo terminal created and therefore programs that uses line buffering works. This also ensures your login profile is executed so that you get correct environment setup for the user too. Also screen based commands like vim works only if you use -t flag.

This blog has some nice tips btw
http://lugatgt.org/2009/10/28/ssh-tips-and-tricks-2/

Comment: Technically, it's `grep` which is buffering output by blocks instead of by lines, because its output isn't to a TTY.